# webpack globby stop dip into subdirs when find a index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have modules like src/a/index.js, src/a/b/index.js, src/c/d/index.js.

`var globby = require('globby');
var files = globby.sync(['**/pages/**'], {cwd: cwd + '/src'});`

Js above may get 3 index.js, is there a way to get `index.js`s only in `src/a` and `src/c/d` ?
That is globby `index.js`s at top-most directories.

Answer (score 0):

I work out a solution:

```
var dirs = globby.sync(['**/pages/*'], {cwd: cwd + '/src'});
var dirsTmp = [];
while (dirs.length > 0) {
    dirsTmp = [];
    dirs.forEach(item => {
        if (fs.existsSync(`./src/${item}/index.js`)) {
            entry[item + '/index'] = [`./src/${item}/index.js`];
        } else {
            dirsTmp = dirsTmp.concat( globby.sync([`**/${item}/*`], {cwd: `${cwd}/src`}) );
        }
    });
    dirs = dirsTmp;
}
```